# RESTful Microservice failover & load balancing

Tags: spring-boot, load-balancing, failover, microservices

At the moment we have some monolithic Web Applications and try to transfer the projects to an microservices infrastructure.

For the monolithic application is an HAProxy and Session Replication to have failover and load balancing.

Now we build some RESTful microservices with spring boot but it's not clear for me what is the best way to build the production environment. 
Of course we can run all applications as unix services and still have a reverse proxy for load balancing and failover. This solution seems very heavy for me and have a lot of configuration and maintenance. Resource Management and scaling up or down servers will be always a manually process.

What are the best possibilities to setup production environment with 2-3 Servers and easy resource management? 
Is there some solution the also support continuous deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend looking into service discovery. [Netflix](https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki/Service-Discovery) descibes this as:

> A Service Discovery system provides a mechanism for:
>
> - Services to register their availability
> - Locating a single instance of a particular service
> - Notifying when the instances of a service change

Packages such as Netflix's Eureka could be of help. (EDIT - actually this looks like it might be AWS specific)

This should work well with continuous delivery as the services can make themselves unavailable, be updated and then register availability again.

Comment: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html I haven't used it but there is a section about Using Eureka on Cloudfoundry so there is a chance that it might work also outside AWS

Comment: As i understand it, the curator project helps me to discover a available service. Is there also a solution to automatically manage servers? 
If on server goes online services will started there, if on server goes offline services will start on other one?

Cloudfoundry is a little bit confusing for me :(